# Maya plugin compile problems with cmake and VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, cmake, maya

I am trying to compile the example plugin found at [Maya API](http://docs.autodesk.com/MAYAUL/2013/ENU/Maya-API-Documentation/files/Command_plugins_MFnPlugin.htm) using cmake to create a Visual Studio 2012 project. However there seems to be a number of problems when compiling the libraries shipped with Maya. The first problem was the library trying to compensate for some old missing bool implementation, this was solved by adding the preprocessor definition

```
add_definitions(-D _BOOL)
```

To the cmake file.

The next error from their library is a problem where it tries to acces std::ostream but are unable to find it in 'std', this is solved using another definition in cmake:

```
add_definitions(-D REQUIRE_IOSTREAM)
```

This leads to a final error I have been unable to get through, I have both googled it, looked over stackoverflow and looked in the sample VSproject files that ship with maya, unable to solve it.
The errors(18 total) stems from the linker, and are all unresolved external symbols, example error:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall MStatus::MStatus(enum MStatus::MStatusCode)" (__imp_??0MStatus@@QAE@W4MStatusCode@0@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual class MStatus __thiscall hello::doIt(class MArgList const &)" (?doIt@hello@@UAE?AVMStatus@@ABVMArgList@@@Z) C:\path\mayacmake_sample\helloworld.obj Sample_helloworld
```

**Edit:**
Using a modified cmakelist from Andreas have not yielded any difference:
Hey, Thanks for the reply, but I still get a lot of errors with inresolved externals:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall MStatus::MStatus(enum MStatus::MStatusCode)" (__imp_??0MStatus@@QAE@W4MStatusCode@0@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual class MStatus __thiscall hello::doIt(class MArgList const &)" (?doIt@hello@@UAE?AVMStatus@@ABVMArgList@@@Z) D:\mayacmake_sample\helloworld.obj  Maya_Sample_Plugin
Error   13  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall MPxCommand::hasSyntax(void)const " (?hasSyntax@MPxCommand@@UBE_NXZ)  D:\mayacmake_sample\helloworld.obj  Maya_Sample_Plugin
```

I cut out the other errors as they look the same as the two above.
I made sure to modify the paths in the cmake file to fit my install, it now looks as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)

SET(MAYA_PLUGIN_NAME "Maya_Sample_Plugin")
SET(MAYA_DIRECTORY "C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2013")
SET(MAYA_HEADERS_DIR "${MAYA_DIRECTORY}/include")
SET(MAYA_LIBRARY_DIR "${MAYA_DIRECTORY}/lib")

SET(SOURCE_FILES
  helloworld.cpp 
)

source_group("" FILES ${SOURCE_FILES})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(
  ${MAYA_HEADERS_DIR}
  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}
)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(
  ${MAYA_LIBRARY_DIR}
)

SET(LIBRARIES
  Foundation.lib
  OpenMaya.lib
  OpenMayaAnim.lib
  OpenMayaUI.lib
)

SET(MAYA_DEFINITIONS _AFXDLL _MBCS NT_PLUGIN REQUIRE_IOSTREAM _BOOL)

ADD_LIBRARY(${MAYA_PLUGIN_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${MAYA_PLUGIN_NAME} ${LIBRARIES})

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${MAYA_PLUGIN_NAME} PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "${MAYA_DEFINITIONS}")
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${MAYA_PLUGIN_NAME} PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "${MAYA_PLUGIN_NAME}")
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${MAYA_PLUGIN_NAME} PROPERTIES SUFFIX ".mll")
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${MAYA_PLUGIN_NAME} PROPERTIES CLEAN_DIRECT_OUTPUT 1)
```

Any help in the matter is appriciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell the linker which libs to link against, done with `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES`. Here's what I use in my CMakeLists.txt.

```
SET(MAYA_PLUGIN_NAME "myCoolPlugin")
SET(MAYA_DIRECTORY "D:/Program Files (x86)/Autodesk Maya2011")
SET(MAYA_HEADERS_DIR "${MAYA_DIRECTORY}/include")
SET(MAYA_LIBRARY_DIR "${MAYA_DIRECTORY}/lib")

SET(SOURCE_FILES
  myCoolPlugin.cpp 
)

source_group("" FILES ${SOURCE_FILES})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${MAYA_HEADERS_DIR})
LINK_DIRECTORIES(${MAYA_LIBRARY_DIR})

SET(LIBRARIES Foundation.lib OpenMaya.lib OpenMayaAnim.lib OpenMayaUI.lib)

SET(MAYA_DEFINITIONS _AFXDLL _MBCS NT_PLUGIN REQUIRE_IOSTREAM _BOOL)

ADD_LIBRARY(${MAYA_PLUGIN_NAME} SHARED ${SOURCE_FILES})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${MAYA_PLUGIN_NAME} ${LIBRARIES})

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${MAYA_PLUGIN_NAME} PROPERTIES COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "${MAYA_DEFINITIONS}")
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${MAYA_PLUGIN_NAME} PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME "${MAYA_PLUGIN_NAME}")
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${MAYA_PLUGIN_NAME} PROPERTIES SUFFIX ".mll")
SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${MAYA_PLUGIN_NAME} PROPERTIES CLEAN_DIRECT_OUTPUT 1)

SET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(${MAYA_PLUGIN_NAME} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "/export:initializePlugin /export:uninitializePlugin")
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, I have tried to modify your cmake file, but I still get the same errors. I can compile the file through visual studio, but not build it, so the linker step wont work. I just tested the sourcecode itself with the MayaPluginWizard, and that worked fine, I also tried to use VS10 as generator for cmake, no difference.

Comment: Alright, check the project properties in VS, Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies. Does it list the Maya libs (OpenMaya.lib etc)?

Comment: I have the following dependencies aoart from the windows ones: Foundation.lib;OpenMaya.lib;OpenMayaAnim.lib;OpenMayaUI.lib

Comment: Well that's really all it should take to fix these linker errors. I just checked, and I get the same missing "MStatus::MStatus(enum MStatus::MStatusCode)" errors when I remove OpenMaya.lib. If the linker was unable to find the libs it would say so. Are you sure there aren't any other errors? Are you sure you're loading the correct solution?

Comment: Okay, here is my process:
0. cmake .\CMakeLists.txt (contents in original post)
1. Open "Project.sln" created in the same directory
2a. From VS10/12 Build->Build all. Set of linker errors as above
2b. From VS10/12 right click Maya_Sample_Plugin project (ignoring ALL_BUILD and ZERO_CHECK) and click build, same linker errors.

Er get the following linker errors LNK2001 and LNK201, both are texted "Unresolved external symbol"

Am I missing something crucial?

Comment: I just tried it with your CMakeLists.txt, and that sample plugin builds fine for me, no errors. The only thing I changed was the Maya path.

Comment: Ah, I know what it is. You have the 64 bit version of Maya, but you're using the 32 bit project generator in CMake. Try the "VS 11 Win64" generator instead.

Comment: I have marked your post as answer and will move the further question to an individual "question" since the original topic here is solved, thanks!